# `gazebo_ros_ft_sensor plugin error: jointName: FT_sensor does not exist` on GEN3-KINOVA arm

Tags: ros-noetic, gazebo-11, gazebo-sensor, force-sensor, kinova

Here is my urdf.xacro file (original gen3 urdf.xacro found [here](https://github.com/Kinovarobotics/ros_kortex/blob/noetic-devel/kortex_description/arms/gen3/7dof/urdf/gen3_macro.xacro)):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<robot name="gen3_arm" xmlns:xacro="http://ros.org/wiki/xacro">

  <!-- Propagate last link name information because it is the gripper's parent link -->
  <xacro:property name="last_arm_link" value="end_effector_link"/>

  <xacro:macro name="load_arm" params="parent:='' dof vision prefix *origin">
      <link name="${prefix}base_link">
    <inertial>
      <origin xyz="-0.000648 -0.000166 0.084487" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <mass value="1.697" />
      <inertia ixx="0.004622" ixy="9E-06" ixz="6E-05" iyy="0.004495" iyz="9E-06" izz="0.002079" />
    </inertial>
    <visual>
      <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
      <geometry>
        <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/base_link.STL" />
          </geometry>
          <material name="">
            <color rgba="0.75294 0.75294 0.75294 1" />
          </material>
        </visual>
        <collision>
          <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
          <geometry>
            <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/base_link.STL" />
      </geometry>
    </collision>
</link>
<link name="${prefix}shoulder_link">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="-2.3E-05 -0.010364 -0.07336" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <mass value="1.3773" />
        <inertia ixx="0.00457" ixy="1E-06" ixz="2E-06" iyy="0.004831" iyz="0.000448" izz="0.001409" />
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/shoulder_link.STL" />
    </geometry>
    <material name="">
      <color rgba="0.75294 0.75294 0.75294 1" />
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/shoulder_link.STL" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <joint
      name="${prefix}joint_1"
  type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0 0 0.15643" rpy="3.1416 2.7629E-18 -4.9305E-36" />
  <parent
    link="${prefix}base_link" />
      <child
        link="${prefix}shoulder_link" />
  <axis
    xyz="0 0 1" />
  <limit
    effort="39"
    velocity="1.3963" />
</joint>
<link name="${prefix}half_arm_1_link">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="-4.4E-05 -0.09958 -0.013278" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <mass value="1.1636" />
        <inertia ixx="0.011088" ixy="5E-06" ixz="0" iyy="0.001072" iyz="-0.000691" izz="0.011255" />
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/half_arm_1_link.STL" />
    </geometry>
    <material name="">
      <color rgba="0.75294 0.75294 0.75294 1" />
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/half_arm_1_link.STL" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <joint
      name="${prefix}joint_2"
  type="revolute">
  <origin xyz="0 0.005375 -0.12838" rpy="1.5708 2.1343E-17 -1.1102E-16" />
  <parent
    link="${prefix}shoulder_link" />
      <child
        link="${prefix}half_arm_1_link" />
  <axis
    xyz="0 0 1" />
  <limit lower="-2.41" upper="2.41" effort="39" velocity="1.3963" />
</joint>
<link name="${prefix}half_arm_2_link">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="-4.4E-05 -0.006641 -0.117892" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <mass value="1.1636" />
        <inertia ixx="0.010932" ixy="0" ixz="-7E-06" iyy="0.011127" iyz="0.000606" izz="0.001043" />
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/half_arm_2_link.STL" />
    </geometry>
    <material name="">
      <color rgba="0.75294 0.75294 0.75294 1" />
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/half_arm_2_link.STL" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <joint
      name="${prefix}joint_3"
  type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0 -0.21038 -0.006375" rpy="-1.5708 1.2326E-32 -2.9122E-16" />
  <parent
    link="${prefix}half_arm_1_link" />
      <child
        link="${prefix}half_arm_2_link" />
  <axis
    xyz="0 0 1" />
  <limit
    effort="39"
    velocity="1.3963" />
</joint>
<link name="${prefix}forearm_link">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="-1.8E-05 -0.075478 -0.015006" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <mass value="0.9302" />
        <inertia ixx="0.008147" ixy="-1E-06" ixz="0" iyy="0.000631" iyz="-0.0005" izz="0.008316" />
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/forearm_link.STL" />
    </geometry>
    <material name="">
      <color rgba="0.75294 0.75294 0.75294 1" />
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/forearm_link.STL" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <joint
      name="${prefix}joint_4"
  type="revolute">
  <origin xyz="0 0.006375 -0.21038" rpy="1.5708 -6.6954E-17 -1.6653E-16" />
  <parent
    link="${prefix}half_arm_2_link" />
      <child
        link="${prefix}forearm_link" />
  <axis
    xyz="0 0 1" />
  <limit lower="-2.66" upper="2.66" effort="39" velocity="1.3963" />
</joint>
<link name="${prefix}spherical_wrist_1_link">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="1E-06 -0.009432 -0.063883" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <mass value="0.6781" />
        <inertia ixx="0.001596" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.001607" iyz="0.000256" izz="0.000399" />
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/spherical_wrist_1_link.STL" />
    </geometry>
    <material name="">
      <color rgba="0.75294 0.75294 0.75294 1" />
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/spherical_wrist_1_link.STL" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <joint
      name="${prefix}joint_5"
  type="continuous">
  <origin xyz="0 -0.20843 -0.006375" rpy="-1.5708 2.2204E-16 -6.373E-17" />
  <parent
    link="${prefix}forearm_link" />
      <child
        link="${prefix}spherical_wrist_1_link" />
  <axis
    xyz="0 0 1" />
  <limit
    effort="9"
    velocity="1.2218" />
</joint>
<link name="${prefix}spherical_wrist_2_link">
      <inertial>
        <origin xyz="1E-06 -0.045483 -0.00965" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <mass value="0.6781" />
        <inertia ixx="0.001641" ixy="0" ixz="0" iyy="0.00041" iyz="-0.000278" izz="0.001641" />
      </inertial>
      <visual>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/spherical_wrist_2_link.STL" />
    </geometry>
    <material name="">
      <color rgba="0.75294 0.75294 0.75294 1" />
    </material>
  </visual>
  <collision>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/spherical_wrist_2_link.STL" />
        </geometry>
      </collision>
    </link>
    <joint
      name="${prefix}joint_6"
  type="revolute">
  <origin xyz="0 0.00017505 -0.10593" rpy="1.5708 9.2076E-28 -8.2157E-15" />
  <parent
    link="${prefix}spherical_wrist_1_link" />
      <child
        link="${prefix}spherical_wrist_2_link" />
  <axis
    xyz="0 0 1" />
  <limit lower="-2.23" upper="2.23" effort="9" velocity="1.2218" />
</joint>
<xacro:if value="${vision}">
    <link name="${prefix}bracelet_link">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="0.000281 0.011402 -0.029798" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <mass value="0.5" />
    <inertia ixx="0.000587" ixy="3E-06" ixz="3E-06" iyy="0.000369" iyz="-0.000118" izz="0.000609" />
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/bracelet_with_vision_link.STL" />
        </geometry>
        <material name="">
          <color rgba="0.75294 0.75294 0.75294 1" />
        </material>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/bracelet_with_vision_link.STL" />
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>
</xacro:if>
<xacro:unless value="${vision}">
    <link name="${prefix}bracelet_link">
  <inertial>
    <origin xyz="-9.3E-05 0.000132 -0.022905" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <mass value="0.364" />
    <inertia ixx="0.000214" ixy="0" ixz="1E-06" iyy="0.000223" iyz="-2E-06" izz="0.00024" />
  </inertial>
  <visual>
    <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
    <geometry>
      <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/bracelet_no_vision_link.STL" />
        </geometry>
        <material name="">
          <color rgba="0.75294 0.75294 0.75294 1" />
        </material>
      </visual>
      <collision>
        <origin xyz="0 0 0" rpy="0 0 0" />
        <geometry>
          <mesh filename="package://kortex_description/arms/gen3/${dof}dof/meshes/bracelet_no_vision_link.STL" />
    </geometry>
  </collision>
</link>
</xacro:unless>
<joint
  name="${prefix}joint_7"
      type="continuous">
      <origin xyz="0 -0.10593 -0.00017505" rpy="-1.5708 -5.5511E-17 9.6396E-17" />
      <parent
        link="${prefix}spherical_wrist_2_link" />
  <child
    link="${prefix}bracelet_link" />
      <axis
        xyz="0 0 1" />
      <limit
        effort="9"
        velocity="1.2218" />
    </joint>
    
    <link name="${prefix}end_effector_link" />
<joint
  name="${prefix}end_effector"
      type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="0 0 -0.0615250000000001" rpy="3.14159265358979 1.09937075168372E-32 0" />
      <parent
        link="${prefix}bracelet_link" />
  <child
    link="${prefix}end_effector_link" />
      <axis
        xyz="0 0 0" />
    </joint>
    
    
    <link name="FT_sensor_link"/>
    <joint name="FT_sensor" type="fixed">
      <origin xyz="0 0.05639 -0.00305" rpy="3.14159265358979 3.14159265358979 0" />
      <parent link="${prefix}end_effector_link" />
      <child link="FT_sensor_link"/>
    </joint>
      
    <gazebo reference='FT_sensor'>
      <disableFixedJointLumping>true</disableFixedJointLumping>
      <preserveFixedJoint>true</preserveFixedJoint>
    </gazebo>
      
    <gazebo>
      <plugin name="Force_Torque_sensor" filename="libgazebo_ros_ft_sensor.so">
        <updateRate>100.0</updateRate>
        <topicName>ft_sensor_topic</topicName>
        <jointName>FT_sensor</jointName>
      </plugin>
    </gazebo>
    
    <xacro:if value="${vision}">
  <link name="${prefix}camera_link" />
      <joint name="${prefix}camera_module" type="fixed">
    <origin xyz="0 0.05639 -0.00305" rpy="3.14159265358979 3.14159265358979 0" />
    <parent link="${prefix}end_effector_link" />
        <child  link="${prefix}camera_link" />
      </joint>
      
      <link name="${prefix}camera_depth_frame" />
  <joint name="${prefix}depth_module" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0.0275 0.066 -0.00305" rpy="3.14159265358979 3.14159265358979 0" />
        <parent link="${prefix}end_effector_link" />
    <child  link="${prefix}camera_depth_frame" />
      </joint>
      
      <link name="${prefix}camera_color_frame" />
  <joint name="${prefix}color_module" type="fixed">
        <origin xyz="0 0.05639 -0.00305" rpy="3.14159265358979 3.14159265358979 0" />
        <parent link="${prefix}end_effector_link" />
    <child  link="${prefix}camera_color_frame" />
      </joint>
    </xacro:if>
    

    
    
       
  </xacro:macro>
</robot>
```

I am a beginner. My initial problem is that gazebo does not recognize the 'FT_sensor' joint (error: `[FATAL] [1701011286.835621614]: gazebo_ros_ft_sensor plugin error: jointName: FT_sensor does not exist`)
I tried multiple times, and with multiple solutions to run the gz sdf -p to see how the 'FT_sensor'fixed joint could be recognized in the .sdf that gazebo is taking it but no chance.
Any help would be welcomed. Thank you for your time!